# Can I use Cloud Functions for Firebase to run a web scraper twice a day?

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm currently trying to build a simple web scraper to get prices from Amazon (and other sites) products and save it to Firestore and use it in my Firebase app.

I was thinking about using Google App Engine to run the code (maybe update the prices twice a day).

Can I use Cloud Functions for Firebase to do that?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Thanks! I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like it might be a better fit for one or more Cloud Functions, as one of their use cases is event- or cron-driven activation, while App Engine is really intended more for web apps, although either could probably work. I'm assuming you are looking at these for their serverless and scale-to-zero properties.

You can use Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub to kick off the Cloud Function. See cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub

Comment: Found this while researching on it: [Cron Cloud Functions with App Engine](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html). It uses Cloud Functions and App Engine. Is there a way to do it with Cloud Functions only, without using App Engine Cron feature?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you need to use an external event source like a call from App Engine triggered by cron. Of course, you can also use any other source that could generate an http call twice a day if you already have any resources that can do that.

Comment: I'll go with that! Cloud Functions + App Engine Cron job. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you can use Cloud Scheduler and Pub/Sub to kick off the Cloud Function and skip the App Engine part. See https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/tut-pub-sub

Comment: I've just also found out about it! I've tested and it works. No need for App Engine, although I think it uses App Engine behind the scenes. I say that because lots of the headers from the Cron Job's request are App Engine-related. Like `x-appengine-api-ticket`, `x-appengine-country`, etc. Thanks. You should edit and add that to your answer.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do that. Thanks.